# Ubuntu docker user doesnt have dns but root does

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dns

When using another user than root inside a ubuntu docker container I cannot access urls.

This works just fine

```
su - "user" -s "/bin/sh" -c "ping 8.8.8.8"
```

This fails with ping: google.com: Name or service not known but works as root

```
su - "user" -s "/bin/sh" -c "ping google.com"
```

Just to be sure this also fails as a user curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com

```
su - "user" -s "/bin/sh" -c "curl google.com"
```

Im not sure if im missing something in the docker ubuntu image or what to do.

I have tried changing permissions on /etc/resolv.conf but that doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile to the question?  Why are you trying to use `su` here?  Does deleting the container and re-running the same `docker run` command improve things at all?